# Getting the mime type of an raw image using CoreServices

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Using the file extension of a file called `image.raw` I first get the UTI using

```
UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);
```

this returns a CFStringRef which I can then convert to the mime type using

```
UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
```

For my raw image the UTI is `com.panasonic.raw-image` but the mime type is `application/octet-stream` instead of `image/x-panasonic-raw` what I had expected.

Is this to be expected?